# Files pinned to my IPFS node don't show up on any other gateway

Tags: ipfs

Everything seems to be working properly. I can see my files at http://[localhost]:8080/ipfs/[cid] or http://[public IP]:8080/ipfs/[cid]

The same CID shows the following error at ipfs.io and many other gateways I tried

> The gateway is taking too long to fetch your content. This could be
> due to several reasons:
>
> The CID does not exist in the IPFS network
>
> The host that contains the CID has gone offline, is on a slow network connection or overloaded

http://localhost:5001/webui shows everything working. The node is connected to many peers. There is data going in and out. There are no apparent errors or problems.

Do I need to open any ports besides 8080? I tried also opening 4001 but it didn't help. 5001 and 8080 are the ports I see the server running on when I start it up.

How else can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: what public gateway are you using? using your own node will work well but you should try to fetch the content from a public gateway. Like https://ipfs.io

Comment: How long after pinning your content do you wait before fetching it. Propagation is not so fast.